# USB Stack for LPC1343

Tags: usb, usb-device, lpc, nxp, lpcxpresso

I was trying to implement a USB keyboard on LPC1343 using the ROM based HID driver when I came across some information on the internet which stated that the ROM based HID driver is very limited in terms of flexibility and using it for a keyboard project is not feasible. I took a look at the open source LPCUSBlib but it seems that it does not support LPC1343 (although it works on LPC1347).

I wanted to know if there are any other open source / free USB stacks for the LPC1343 which I can use for my HID keyboard project? I could have spent some time to look into the possibility of porting the LPCUSBlib to the LPC1343 but I do not have much time.

P.S.: I am using a custom LPC1343 based hardware and LPCXpresso IDE for my development

Answer (score 1):

> open source / free USB stacks for the LPC1343

The CCC `R0ket` has [open source firmware](https://github.com/r0ket/r0ket). The included USB CDC stack looks a lot like a full blown USB stack with HID support. Note that this stack is not used in the default build - it uses ROM code for USB.

I've seen this stack (or very similar variants) for NXP µCs elswhere on the web, including HID example code.

Comment: The USB files look like those from the microbuilder code base which uses the HID ROM code. The problem with it is that I am not able to get the device detected as a USB keyboard since most of the values in the report descriptor are hardcoded. A full software stack would allow me to define my own report descriptor. The nxpUSBlib looks promising but it looks like a lot of work to port it to LPC1343.

Comment: The `usbcdc` folder contains full USB software stack without using ROM.